# How can I translate categories for JoomGallery?

Tags: multilingual, joomla2.5

On my multilingual joomla 2.5 page I would like to use [JoomGallery](http://www.joomgallery.net). The images are asigned to categories. How can I make those categories depending on the webpage current language?

Thank you.
Spikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: translation of categories is not supported yet. As a workaround you can use the string stranslation feature of joomla. My excuse for the quick-and-dirty touch of the design: main target was to be able to change the translation for an administrator in the backend without any changes to the administration code. The example below takes german as its base language this means:

1. every category name is entered in german (e.g. "Katgeorie 1")
2. we create a new constant with an equal name like its german version, but modified to the namespace possabilities (e.g. "CATEGORY1"). This will allow an automated matching.
3. in the template code we replace the category outputs, if we are on another language page than the original (here german).

The following functions help to automatically get the correct constant values in other languages.

```
/**
 * Remove umlauts and special chars.
 */
if(!function_exists('toASCII')) {
   function toASCII($str) {   
         $str = mb_strtolower($str,'UTF-8'); // Useful if the current server setting is not UTF-8
         //$str = strtolower($str);
         $str = preg_replace( '#ß#'    , "ss",    $str );    // maps German ß onto ss
         $str = preg_replace( '#ä#'    , "ae",    $str );    // Æ => AE
         $str = preg_replace( '#ö#'    , "oe",    $str );    // Œ => OE
         $str = preg_replace( '#ü#'    , "ue",    $str );    // œ => oe
         $str = preg_replace( '#Ä#'    , "ae",    $str );    // Æ => AE
         $str = preg_replace( '#Ö#'    , "oe",    $str );    // Œ => OE
         $str = preg_replace( '#Ü#'    , "ue",    $str );    // œ => oe
         $str = preg_replace( '# #'    , "",    $str );        // remove spaces
         $str = preg_replace( '#-#'    , "",    $str );        // remove hyphens
         $str = preg_replace( "#'#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         $str = preg_replace( "#/#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         $str = preg_replace( "#\(#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         $str = preg_replace( "#\)#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         $str = preg_replace( "#\.#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         $str = preg_replace( "#,#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         $str = preg_replace( "#\[#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         $str = preg_replace( "#\]#"    , "",    $str );        // remove apostrophs
         // Process all other special chars
         $str = strtr(utf8_decode($str), 
                utf8_decode('ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
                'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
         return strtoupper($str);
   }
}

function translate($de_string) {

   // Translate all JoomGallery category names
   $menu = JFactory::getApplication()->getMenu();
   $active = $menu->getActive();
   $activeItemLanguage = $active->language;
   $lang = substr($activeItemLanguage, 0, 2);

   // Do not translate german category names
   $trans_str = $de_string;
   if ($lang != "de") {
      // Parse all category names and replace them with an existing override-string.
      $const = toASCII($trans_str);
      $trans_str = JText::_($const);
   }
   return $trans_str;
}
```

How to use this: replace the string functions in the templates that show category names:

```
<?php echo translate($this->escape($row->name)); ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php echo $this->escape($row->name); ?>
```